# sessions in jsp doesnot seem to work properly

Tags: jsp, session

I have to develop a web application where the values user inputs in the login page are used by more than one jsp page .So I used sessions for it.It works fine when I register as a user and login again.But once I restart the computer,it shows null value in session.getAttribute().What might be the problem?

here is the code in login.jsp

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/vaishnavi","root","atreyasa");

    name=request.getParameter("username");
    password=request.getParameter("password");

    st=con.createStatement();
    st1=con.createStatement();

    rs=st.executeQuery("select * from admins where username='"+name+"' and password='"+password+"'");
    rs1=st1.executeQuery("select * from admins where username='"+name+"' and password!='"+password+"'");

    if(rs!=null&&rs.next()){
        session.setAttribute("username",name);
        response.sendRedirect("http://127.0.0.1:8080/Project_programs/home.jsp");
    }
    else if(rs1!=null&&rs.next()){
        out.println("Enter correct password");
    }
    else{
    response.sendRedirect("http://127.0.0.1:8080/Project_programs/register.jsp");
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    out.println(e);
}
```

Home.jsp which accesses session.getAttribute()

```
out.println("<h1 align=center>Welcome "+session.getAttribute("username")+"</h1>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed, the `session` is erased after you restart your machine. That is due to the temporary nature of the `session` property. It is stored in the memory, so when you restart your computer, it is erased.

The solution here is to use `cookies`. `Cookies` are small chunks of data stored on the client's computer, which are sent with every request a client makes.
So, when a user requests a page, you can check if he has a `cookie`, and if he does, then you can read the data from the cookie and sign him in without him entering credentials again.

Setting cookies with servlet involves three steps:

(1) Creating a Cookie object: You call the Cookie constructor with a cookie name and a cookie value, both of which are strings.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("key","value");
```

Keep in mind, neither the name nor the value should contain white space or any of the following characters:[ ] ( ) = , " / ? @ : ;

(2) Setting the maximum age: You use `setMaxAge` to specify how long (in seconds) the cookie should be valid. Following would set up a cookie for 24 hours.

```
cookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24);
```

(3) Sending the Cookie into the HTTP response headers: You use `response.addCookie` to add cookies in the HTTP response header as follows:

```
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

That stores the cookie on the client's computer when he receives the response.

You can read a more elaborate tutorial on cookies at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-cookies-handling.htm

Best,
Jovan.

Comment: Well, but session will be created again for the new jsp request rignt? and  I am setting those values again in the session.setAttribute()....Iam still not able to access.Also i just noticed that this is for the first login attempt after restarting....Once i logout and login again it works fine

Comment: That's right, a session is contained within the request a client sends.
If I got it right, you restart your machine, try to access the page and it asks for you login credentials? Then, when you provide (i.e. login), it runs smoothly from there on?
If that's so, it's perfectly normal, since the session is, as I mentioned in my response above, of impermanent nature and is removed when restarting your machine.

Comment: Well once I give the login credentials...it shows session value null for the first time after I restart(or close and open the browser) and works if I login again after that

Comment: The problem is that you are doing all this business logic stuff on your jsp page! You have to do it in a servlet, and then redirect to a jsp page based on the existence of cookie.
If you don't wanna do that, then just put an if statement above everything else that will check if the request has a session. Like this:
'try{

Comment: Just add and if statement that checks if you have a session on the top of your jsp file. That's as much as I can help you.

It would mean a lot to me if you could upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for create session.

```
 CreateSession(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("useremail", user_useremail);
  }
```

Comment: But session is an implicit object right? What is the need to create it again?